# Team Foundation Server: how to split changes to separate check-ins?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, commit

I work in Visual Studio on C# project.

I edit some files it that project **simultaneously**. After some work is done i want to divide all changes to "groups" of changes and commit each group changes to separate commit. Its okay when it comes to files - i include one files, exclude others and all is fine.

But problem appears when some changes are in the single common text file. I'd like to split them to different check-ins by TFS itslf, but as far as i know it is not possible.

So tell me please, is there any way to split changes **to distinguish them due development process**? For example when i start editing common file i press something button or issue a command. Later, when i have to add changes regarding to another check-in to that file, **before** these changes are really done, i press another button (another command) and since this moment changes are *recording* as needed to be commited to another check-in.

I hope you understand what i mean. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to make a quick change to a file that has work in progress, you should shelve the changes and revert to the source control version (uncheck the "preserve pending changes" box). Then you can make the changes and check in the file. After that, unshelve your changes (your work in progress) from earlier, VS will merge the changes with your checking and you can carry on.

Since it sounds like you have already made the changes and the file contains code you are ready to check in and code you don't, one thing you can do is to shelve the changes now (but do "preserve pending changes"). Then you can delete any code that aren't ready and check in the file. After check in, you can unshelve your changes.

You might want to consider using branches to isolate your long-running changes; although that has its own set of problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could create another workspace on your computer, and use each workspace for a different task. That way, you can work simultaneously on different tasks on the same file without affecting each-other. When you check-in from one workspace, do a "get latest" on the other workspace and merge the changes there before you check-in the other work.